# How to parametrize a general jordan curve un this integral on the complex plane?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, curves

Let $ \gamma$ be a Jordan curve and denote by $S$ the area on the inside of this curve. Prove that

$$\int_\gamma x\,dz = -i\int_\gamma y \, dz = \frac 1 2 \int_\gamma \bar{z} \, dz = iS$$

how am i suposed to parametrize this Jordan curve in terms of $x$ and $y$ to integrate?

Comment: Yes, you are supposed to do that...or to use the equivalent to Green theorem here. Take a peek at http://mathinsight.org/greens_theorem_find_area

Comment: Why do you put \displaystyle three times into one line when the first one would be enough because it would have the same effect, and why do you use \displaystyle at all when using an actual _display_ could be done and would be appropriate? $\qquad$

Comment: But then what i do about $dz$? if the $dz$ on $x$ are $dx$ and in $y$ $dy$ we will have that $\int_\gamma x\,dz =0= -i\int_\gamma ydz$

Comment: can i say that $dz = dx+idy$?